# Sonicwall Access Rule - Limit Access to Specific IP

Tags: firewall, vpn, access-rules

I have a SonicWall TZ200 and used the Wizard to create a port forwarding for PPTP which is working great.  Now, I want to limit the EXTERNAL IP addresses that can use this port forwarding rule so that it only allows connections from a couple employees static home IP addresses.

I created an Address Object for the external home IP address.  Then I went to Access Rules WAN>LAN.  For the PPTP rule I changed Allow Source to the Address Object for the home IP address.

But, I can still access the VPN from a different external IP address so it's obviously not blocking anything else.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your NAT policy. The "Home" IP addresses are added at the "Original Destination" part of your policy.